# Flink Flame graph stuck infinitely in collecting samples stage

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flamegraph

I am using Flink 1.16 version with JDK-8 and trying to use Flame graph to debug some issues. As per multiple Flink documentation, I just need to add following config in flink-cong.yaml file but for me it is infinitely stuck at "We are waiting for the first samples to create a flame graph" state [Screenshot attached]

```
rest.flamegraph.enabled : true
```

[image]

[image]